# Where from ServletRequest.getInputStream() reads the content?

Tags: java, file, servlets, inputstream

i make  upload file(size is heavy) request to webserver from browser.

I came to know on net that i can use ServletRequest.getInputStream() method to read it from input stream  and then read it by line by line
to avoid out of memory issues. I have question on method ServletRequst.getInputStream(). Does webserver stores the request
on some file internally and then ServletRequest.getInputStream() read it from there . Is that correct ?

**EDIT:-** I am using tomcat server.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream%28%29

Comment: I think this depends on your server, but the JavaEE specification don't says that it will be saved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say *internally* this implies it is implementation detail and you dont have to care about it.

You have on the other hand a specificationn, ist is the [ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) Interface, and it provides you with an `InputStream`, and this ist great! You wont run into memory problems if your read it in a proper way.

Whether it is correct or not is known only by the guys who write the server' code imnplementing the specification.

Comment: i undesratnd we dont have to much worry about. But just out of curiosity , i am trying to find out does request gets stored somewhere on file as soon as it is received ?

Comment: @user3198603, that's cool to be curious :) but I am afraid this information is some inside knowledge, you'll have to investigate on your own, and even if you find out for one app server, other might handle in a totally different way.